# How do I change the start path of git log output?

Tags: git, less, diff-so-fancy

Update: Thanks to [@Brian61354270's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77198278/61624), I've learned I'm asking how to do something with git's `core.pager`. That's customizable (defaults to `less`), but mine is set to `diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX`. I guess this is now a `diff-so-fancy` or `less` question more than a `git` one.

---

I'm not trying to filter logs, I just want the command *output* to start at a different location. I currently use this git alias:

```
[alias]
  lg = log --branches --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%aD)' --abbrev-commit
```

This is perfect most of the time, but if I switch to an old branch and type `git lg`, the output starts on the most recent commit. How do I make the output start at `HEAD` (or another branch/commit) instead? To reiterate, I don't want to filter the output--I want to be able to scroll up and down and see the whole history--I only want to change the *start* of the output screen.

---

My typical workaround is to `git lg` then press <kbd>/</kbd> and type in the branch name. I'm looking for a better workflow.

I read this [Advanced Git log](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log) article and it didn't explain how to do this. It's probably described in `git help log`, but I'm not sure which term to search for: "screen" and "window" don't bring up relevant information.

**Why do I want this?** I'm looking for a branch I created long ago that might have useful code I could use today. I may have found it, but I'm not sure. To answer that question, it would help to see the commit messages of this branch and "nearby" branches.

Comment: I created https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/issues/477 to see if this is a diff-so-fancy feature.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `--branches` from your alias.

Quoting flag's description:

> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/heads` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

By including that flag, you're making

```
git lg
```

the same a writing

```
git lg <literally every single branch>
```

which of course will always show the history starting with the most recent commit (provided there's branch referencing it). Note that this is essentially the same as using `--all`, just without also implying `HEAD`.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to disable this behavior once it has already been enabled by a previous flag.

Comment: That's useful to know, but removing `--branches` isn't exactly what I'm looking for: yes, it starts output at HEAD (desired behavior), but it seems to truncate any history after/above HEAD (undesired behavior). At least, it appeared that way to me: I couldn't scroll higher than where the output started, nor could I find my main branch in the output. Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Hmm, you're probably out of luck in that case. `git log` doesn't provide the scrolling, it just writes a history to stdout. Scrolling is provided by whichever external pager you have configured (set by `core.pager`, by default it's `less`). That's what you're typing `/` into. I don't think there's any why to prescroll the pager.

Comment: The only incremental improvement I can think of is using `/HEAD` instead of `/branchname` to save a bit of typing and needing to remember the branch name

Comment: Ah, shame. FWIW, I'm using `diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX`. I'm not sure why, I set it to that years ago.

Comment: Oh, and in case others are wondering, the reason I use `--branch` in my alias is to *prevent* this truncating behavior in these types of scenarios. I find I want the full logs more often than not.